# How to upgrade postfix 3

Tags: linux, postfix, yum

I have postfix installed on a server. From what i can tell it was installed using this steps https://computingforgeeks.com/installing-postfix3-on-centos-7/
I was not involved in installing it so i don't have much details. I ran few commands to check and it seems like it's postfix3.
How do i upgrade it to latest version?
When i run `sudo yum upgrade postfix3` i get a message that there are No packages marked for update.
It seems like the package was pulled from Ghettoforge repository from the steps mentioned in the list. The server is amazon linux.

The version i have is 3.4.7 confirmed using `rpm -qi postfix3` but the actual latest version is 3.7.x

Comment: CentOS 7 sounds like something that has not received further upgrades (only some maintenance, and that too will end) for years now. Why do you want a newer release? Depending on that reason, you may want to look into distributors that not only provide a recent Postfix release, but also supply you with further (possibly highly security-relevant) releases for a reasonable timespan.

Answer (score 0):

In RHEL/Centos the name of the package is `postfix`, not `postfix3`. And there distributions do not distribute the latest version of a software, they offer stable and (mostly) bugfree versions. So upgrade to next version of your current OS or migrate to other RHEL variant.
and you can try command like:

```
yum update postfix
```